# Immutable 100%, but still not thread-safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, immutability

I've read a lot about thread-safety. In certain part of my multi-threaded program, I preferred to try the immutability. After getting incorrect results, I noticed my immutable object is not thread-safe although it is 100% immutable. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
public final class ImmutableGaugeV4 {
private final long max, current;

public ImmutableGaugeV4(final long max) {
    this(max, 0);
}

private ImmutableGaugeV4(final long max, final long current) {
    this.max = max;
    this.current = current;
}

public final ImmutableGaugeV4 increase(final long increment) {
    final long c = current;
    return new ImmutableGaugeV4(max, c + increment);
}

public final long getCurrent() {
    return current;
}

public final long getPerc() {
    return current * 100 / max;
}

@Override
public final String toString() {
    return "ImmutableGaugeV4 [max=" + max + ", current=" + current + "](" + getPerc() + "%)";
}
 }
```

aaaaa

```
public class T4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new T4().x();
}

ImmutableGaugeV4 g3 = new ImmutableGaugeV4(10000);

private void x() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                    g3 = g3.increase(1);
                    System.out.println(g3);
                }
            }

        }.start();
    }
}
}
```

Sometimes I'm getting correct results, and most of the times I'm not

```
ImmutableGaugeV4 [max=10000, current=9994](99%)
ImmutableGaugeV4 [max=10000, current=9995](99%)
ImmutableGaugeV4 [max=10000, current=9996](99%)
ImmutableGaugeV4 [max=10000, current=9997](99%)
```

What is wrong with this immutable object? What is missing to make it thread-safe without using intrinsic locks?

Comment: Your class `T4` isn't immutable. That is what you are mutating by reassigning `g3`.

Comment: What's your question?? You produce 4 different immutable objects. It has nothing to do with thread-safety. I am surprised that someone even upvoted this

Answer (score 1):

Neither

```
final long c = current;
return new ImmutableGaugeV4(max, c + increment);
```

nor

```
g3 = g3.increase(1);
```

is thread-safe. These compound actions aren't atomic.

I recommend reading "Java concurrency in practice" by Brian Goetz: the chapters devoted to compound actions and "publication and escape" problems.

Comment: `current` is final, so there is no race possible (final fields are frozen at the end of a constructor). Deriving a new immutable object from an old one is thread safe. Just `g3 = g3.increase(1);` is not, as there can be a race.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not using thread safe operations for your numeric variables max and current. Because of that, many threads can get the same value from them even tough it has already been changed.

You could add synchronized blocks to handle reading / writing to them, but the best approach is to use thread safe classes to handle that for you.

If you need long values, that would be AtomicLong. Take a look at it’s documentation, it has methods to do the operations you want.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html

Whenever you’re multithreading you should go for threadsafe objects, such as the Atomic family, ConcurrentHashMap for maps, and so on.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The only problem here is the following line:

```
g3 = g3.increase(1);
```

This is equivalent to the following lines:

```
var tmp = g3;
tmp = tmp.increase(1);
g3 = tmp;
```

To fix this, you could use a Compare And Swap:

```
private static final VarHandle G3;
static {
    try {
        G3 = MethodHandles.lookup().findVarHandle(T4.class, "g3", ImmutableGaugeV4.class);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException roe) {
        throw new Error(roe);
    }
}
```

And then replace `g3 = g3.increase(1);` with:

```
ImmutableGaugeV4 oldVal, newVal;
do {
    oldVal = g3;
    newVal = oldVal.increase(1);
} while (!G3.compareAndSet(T4.this, oldVal, newVal));
System.out.println(newVal);
```

In the end, your T4 becomes:

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.VarHandle;

public class T4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new T4().x();
    }
    
    ImmutableGaugeV4 g3 = new ImmutableGaugeV4(10000);
    private static final VarHandle G3;
    static {
        try {
            G3 = MethodHandles.lookup().findVarHandle(T4.class, "g3", ImmutableGaugeV4.class);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException roe) {
            throw new Error(roe);
        }
    }
    
    private void x() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                        ImmutableGaugeV4 oldVal, newVal;
                        do {
                            oldVal = g3;
                            newVal = oldVal.increase(1);
                        } while (!G3.compareAndSet(T4.this, oldVal, newVal));
                        System.out.println(newVal);
                    }
                }
                
            }.start();
        }
    }
}
```